# How to print JSON object by Gson without sensitive attributes?

Tags: java, gson

I am using Gson to print objects as JSON but I realise that it prints all things and it also exposes sensitive datas. Anyway to prevent that easily?

Comment: I need to use all the data so I can not use @Expose annotation. Sorry for my bad English..:))

Comment: Please provide two examples: 1) json with sensitive data you do not wish to expose, and 2) the result you are experiencing that includes your data you wish to hide. Moreover, show the code that causes this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the Gson-doc [here](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) you can see the answer to your question. Do not forget to invoke `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`

Comment: Thank you, with `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` I can decide when to show or hide fields.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = true)` over fields that you do not want to expose as JSON. This way you do not convert some fields when converting to JSON format but they are available when you receive a JSON object over the network and want to use those fields.

Answer (score 0):

I just have another way to do it:
Just write the keyword "transient" before the field you want to remove. For example:

```
private transient String emailAddress;
```

"transient" works like just `@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)`. That field will not be present during the serialization as well as the deserialization of your object.